# Datename format in Pentaho Report Designer (Bar Graph)

Tags: date, formula, pentaho, report-designer

I have created a bar graph that provides analysis by week (Monday - Sunday). I need to format the X-axis to display Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc. I have attempted to change the "x-tick-format" within the charts properties but have not found a formula that will give me what I need. Current format is 2013-12-09. I have tried {0, dd} which gives me the day number of week within the month but not the name of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is {0, date, E} which will give you Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun.